# net::err_unknown_url_scheme phone, facebook and telegram link on webview_flutter

Tags: flutter, hyperlink

0

I'm new to mobile development and I can't find the answer to this question: I have a website and the website has links to facebook, telegram and instagram profile. webview_flutter loads the page but when I click on the links it gives me the error net::err_unknown_url_scheme.

this answer is obsolete...

[net::err_unknown_url_scheme phone, whatsapp and telegram link on webview_flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73828737/neterr-unknown-url-scheme-phone-whatsapp-and-telegram-link-on-webview-flutter)

Help me out with a solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

These links are not available in Flutter Webview.

To handle them, you can either:

- open the link in the user's default navigator,
- or if the apps (WhatsApp, Telegram, or even Instagram or Messenger) if they are installed of the device.

To do so, you have to catch the redirection and handle them manually.

If you are using `webview_flutter`, I assume you have a `WebViewController`, used to open your initial webview page, such as : `webViewController.loadRequest(uri);`

The `WebViewController` has an attribute `setNavigationDelegate`, that you can use to handle manually the navigation redirections.

The following code sample catches whatsapp link, and open them in an external app using the `url_launcher` package :

```dart
webViewController
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..setNavigationDelegate(
    NavigationDelegate(
      onNavigationRequest: (request) async {
        // This callback is called each time a link is clicked in the WebView

        try {
          final Uri uri = Uri.parse(request.url);

          // Checks if the link starts with the WhatsApp pattern, here you can also check if it matches Telegram, Messenger, ...
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://api.whatsapp.com')) {
            // Launch in an external application, or browser if the app is not installed on the phone
            await launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);

            // Prevent the redirection to avoid displaying your "net::err_unknown_url_scheme" error
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }

          // For other links, allow the navigation
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        } catch (e) {
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        }
      },
    ),
  )
  ..loadRequest(uri);
```